# Rails: Timestamp that automatically changes after certain duration similar to Facebook?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, timestamp

When you make a post on Facebook it will say "2 seconds" ago and after some time it will update to "about a minute ago". Is there a way to do easily that in rails with the default timestamps? Facebook does this automatically with no page refresh

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure...You can do so with some pretty easy JS.  Take a look at Timeago by Ryan McGeary.  It does exactly what you're looking to do and it's pretty slick.

http://timeago.yarp.com/

Lots of sites use this kind of functionality including Twitter, FB, Basecamp, etc...

Comment: Oh, and be sure to use Ryan's helper towards the bottom of the site (if you're using Rails.)  It makes implementation dead simple.